# DefaultConventions with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am not sure if I am missing something here but can't find the answer anywhere.
In structuremap I can do the following:

```
                x.Scan(scan =>
                {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                });
```

This effectively means: "if while scanning I find an interface ISampleClass, and there is a type SampleClass that implements ISampleClass, then register SampleClass as the default type for ISampleClass".

How do I do this with Autofac?

Autofac seems to provide this:

```
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

which registers all interfaces it finds to whatever concrete types it finds.
Is there a way to get to intelligently register based on the  name of the class and the interface like structuremap does?

This seems like a basic ask of any DI framework.

Answer (score 1):

The `Where` method should fit your needs.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("XXX"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

By the way, you can also use the `As` method that will act as a filter in this case.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .As<IFoo>();
```

Only types that implement `IFoo` will be registered.

You can find further information on assembly scanning on the [documentation page](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html)